# clone repository without commits

Tags: git, github

I want clone specific repository of GitHub, but, without commits, branchs, in the other words: clone master branch and nothing more.

I know I can clone the repository and then just copy all the files except the .git folder, but wanted to know if this is possible.

Comment: You want to clone master branch without cloning branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
git clone -b master --single-branch --depth 1 elsewhere.git here
```

or maybe

```
git archive --remote somewhere.git master | tar -xvf - -C /where/i/want/to/put/it
```

Comment: I copy your code, and only added the github url, but all return error: see that gist: https://gist.github.com/3839860

Comment: The first one seem to require older git. Try without `--single-branch`. As for the second, yes, it doesn't seem to work with github. It may work if you use the same ssh access you used for your first attempt or with github you can simply fetch https://github.com/patrickmaciel/git-essential/zipball/master

Comment: When I try without the - single-branch, works, except for the commits are still present. As for the second, doens't work:  git archive --remote https://github.com/patrickmaciel/git-essential/zipball/master | tar -xvf - -C .

Comment: No, the zipball is not a `git` url. It's just an address where you can get a `.zip` archive of your code. And what do you mean "commits are still present"? Only the tip of the branch is there. If by commits you mean `.git` directory, then get a zipball or tarball: `curl -L -o - https://github.com/patrickmaciel/git-essential/tarball/master |tar -xvf -`

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. But still I have no relationship with my question, I want to use aiming only at GitHub, or local repositories. 

About the commits, it was like I said above: I want to clone the repository but like a new repository, ie without any commits, ie will only download files without versioning.

Comment: I still don't understand. Only files or repository without any commits? What problem are you trying to solve? Getting rid of git metadata, of long transfer time or of history?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17617/discussion-between-patrick-maciel-and-michael-krelin-hacker)